# kendo-grid, jsp, spring rest CRUD, editable false for update

Tags: rest, jsp, spring-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using kendo grid jsp and Spring rest. Trying to make unique field read-only for update.

```
<kendo:dataSource pageSize="5" page="1" serverPaging="true"  serverSorting="true" serverFiltering="false" requestEnd="onRequestEnd" requestStart="onRequestStart" error="onError">
<kendo:dataSource-transport>
<kendo:dataSource-transport-create url="${createUrl}" type="POST"  dataType="json" contentType="application/json" />
<kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="${readUrl}"  type="POST" dataType="json" contentType="application/json"/>
<kendo:dataSource-transport-update url="${updateUrl}"  type="POST" dataType="json" contentType="application/json" />
<kendo:dataSource-transport-destroy url="${destroyUrl}" type="POST" dataType="json" contentType="application/json" /><kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
<script>
     function parameterMap(options,type) { 
        return JSON.stringify(options);
     }
</script>
</kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
</kendo:dataSource-transport>
```

Checking `e.model.isNew() on onRequestStart` event.

```
function onRequestStart(e) {
    alert("e.model::"+e.model);
    if (!e.model.isNew()) {
        e.container.find("td:eq(3)").text(e.model.ViewSuffix);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the below issue,

> e.model is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by implementing function handle_edit(e).

```
     if (!e.model.isNew()) {
      e.container.find("input[name='field']").attr("readonly", true);
     }
```